# How to add a horizontal line every 3rd li element?

Tags: css

EDIT: The real problem http://jsfiddle.net/5C4n5/2/

Say I have a list of UL list of items with fixed width

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
    <li>item6</li>
    <li>item7</li>
    <li>item8</li>
    <li>item9</li>
</ul>
```

Visually, I want to have horizontal dividers separating each row of 3 items

```
item1 | item2 | item3
_____________________

item4 | item5 | item6
_____________________

item7 | item8 | item9
```

If I were to use a table, I can apply a border to TR element. But on a UL, there is no markup for rows. Is there a CSS trick that can be used?

Comment: Why don't you use multiple ul

Comment: You'd need to use jQuery code for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use a simple `border-bottom` for `li`?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XUcQK/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/XUcQK/1/) *(Removed border for last row using `:nth-last-child()` pseudo)*

```
ul {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 170px;
}

ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}

ul:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

If you want to remove the border for last elements use

```
ul li:last-child,
ul li:nth-last-child(2),
ul li:nth-last-child(3) {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Nothing complex here that I need to explain, as far as `ul:after` goes, I've used that to self clear the element because it holds floated `li` elements.

And to remove the last row border, I've used `:last-child` and `:nth-last-child()` pseudos which selects last `li`, second last `li` and third last `li` respectively.

---

If the content is variable in each `li` than you can refer a demonstration created by [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849353/how-to-add-a-horizonal-line-every-3rd-li-element/24849396?noredirect=1#comment38585857_24849396) *(Thank you for that)*

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/B2jyk/1/) *<sup>(Credits : web-tiki)</sup>*

All you need to do is to add

```
ul li:nth-child(3n+4){
    clear:left;    
}
```

to the code, just a note, remove horizontal `padding` on `li` elements, else use `box-sizing: border-box` property to alter the box model behavior.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli if the contents are variable, you can always use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` or better use multiple `ul` elements, I could certainly go with flex just like dystroy did but again, compatibility matters

Comment: @Mr.Alien this solution rely on the LI to stack up against each other without margin. But I already used the padding and margin to create vertical dividers (see edit). Sorry, I know I didn't state this in my original question. I overlooked the easy solution of using border-bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pure CSS solution :

```
ul {
  width : 500px;
  display: block;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 33%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/votijohi/1/edit)

Comment: +1, this is the best solution as it handles arbitrary contents.. (http://jsbin.com/jukesuha/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like : [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mcjX8/)

Use the nth selector:

**CSS:**

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
ul li{float:left;padding:20px;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;}
ul li:nth-child(3n+1){clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this sollution:

**css**

```
ul > li:nth-child(3n+4) {
    clear:left;
}

ul > li:nth-child(3n+3) {
    padding-right: 0;
}

li{
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 15px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29HM7/2/)